# How to side in out the sidebar menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transactions

I have a following page: http://t.qz828.com/wechat/qzzw/qzsbj/index1.html
I want to the sidebar menu slide in like this [demos](http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/) `Slide in on top` effect.When i read the [demos](http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/) source code.I can't understand clearly.
Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1a6x2vow/)

Answer (score 0):

By the *component.css* http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/css/component.css look into the classes after `/* Effect 1: Slide in on top */` 
Javascript changes the css class from the nav-menu.
Can it help you?

Comment: But the css class after `/* Effect 1: Slide in on top */` was so strange. The HTML is `<nav class="st-menu st-effect-1" id="menu-1">`, but the css class in the compoent.css is `.st-effect-1.st-menu-open .st-effect-1.st-menu`. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: From this article http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/ , I have found the answer why the css class is `.st-effect-1.st-menu-open .st-effect-1.st-menu`.